# Test.sh not working with Amazon Alexa

Tags: alexa

I have been trying to get Alexa on to my Rpi. However, when I run the installer I get an error message that test.sh does not work and I cannot proceed. Is there any way to fix this? Thank you!

EDIT 1: I am following this [tutorial](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/diy-amazon-alexa-raspberry-pi/). I have created my amazon developer account and put in the correct things. However, I had some troubles with my Rpi before I got there and I may have screwed something up. I was trying to fix the connection my Rpi had with my auxiliary cord speaker.

Comment: It would be helpful, if you provided more details. For example, what tutorial you are following or a link to a github page or the content of the script...

Comment: @oh.dae.su Alright! Done.